# Folder structure for webpack project

Tags: webpack, sass, directory-structure

This is folder structure that I require,since this repo will be used source for a website hosted on netlify. For the netlify site to work, index.html must be in the root folder of repo. I'm having trouble with configuration for webpack. I've got the images to work as it's supposed to be. The pug and scss and probably js files need to be as below folder structure shows. I've read the documentation for pug-html-loader but there's nothing related to this.

```
Project-name
|--dist
|  |--Images
|  |  |--Img.png
|  |--Pages
|  |  |--Buttons.html
|  |  |--Cards.html
|  |--Styles
|  |  |--main.css
|  |--Js
|  |  |--main.js
|--src
|  |--Images
|  |  |--Img.png
|  |--Pages
|  |  |--Buttons.pug
|  |  |--Cards.pug
|  |--Styles
|  |  |--buttons.scss
|  |  |--cards.scss
|  |  |--main.scss   
|  |--Js
|  |  |--main.js           
|--index.pug
|--index.html
|--index.scss
|--index.css
|--index.js
|--index.bundle.js
|--webpack.config.js
```

Here's my present config for Webpack -

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'),
path = require('path'),
ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
entry: './index.js',
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname,'dist'),
    filename: 'index.bundle.js'
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback:'style-loader',
                use: ['css-loader','sass-loader'],
                publicPath:'/dist',
            })
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]',
                    outputPath:'./images/'
                }  
            }]
        },
        {
            test:/\.pug$/,
            use:['html-loader','pug-html-loader']
        }
    ]
},
devServer: {
    contentBase:path.join(__dirname,'dist'),
    compress:true,
    port:3000,
    stats:'errors-only',
    open:true,
},
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: 'website',
        minify: {
            collapseWhitespace: true
        },
        template:'./index.pug',
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('index.css')
]
}
```

Comment: Could you explain more on what's your actual issue is, with error messages, logs, etc..?

Comment: There isn't any issue, I'm new to webpack and a bit confused about how can i create the folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the [plugin filemanger](https://github.com/gregnb/filemanager-webpack-plugin).